# Gmail sees all of our emails as spam after site has been hacked

Tags: email, spam, gmail

My site was hacked and it was used to send bulk mail.
We cleaned it, changed to basic HTML. 
Moved to another IP, made requests for de-listing. We don't see it anywhere on blacklists anymore.
SPF is set, no unsolicited email is sent thru our web server or from our mail server.

But, Gmail sees all of our emails as spam with note saying something like "This email has been marked as spam because too many emails send from our domain `example.com` was marked as spam. Daily, my colleagues and I don't send more that 20 emails from our domain. We don't use mail server for sending email from another domain.

How can we make Gmail see us as legitimate senders again?

Comment: Keep in mind that some blacklists are domain name based. Some retain information for a year. Some operators cache blacklists for a period. Some operate their own blacklists. You should make sure you check if your domain name appear on any of the blacklists. I like to recommend using this site: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx It seems to be fairly complete.

Comment: Hi, i've already checked, we are not on any list provided by mxtoolbox.com

Answer (score 2):

Google not only depends on third party blacklists but also maintains their own internal blacklist. To remove your domain / IP from gmails blacklist you can use the form located at https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery to report the issue and get it dealt with but Google may not automatically remove the blacklist entry depending on what Google logs showed about the spam being received.